# locale: LC_ALL is empty

Tags: internationalization

In my ~/.profile

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

But $ locale prints empty LC_ALL:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How can I set LC_ALL to "en_US.UTF-8" ?

Comment: `locale` is set by the terminal emulator (Terminal.app) when you start the app and `LC_ALL`  does not need to be set unless you want to change the default `LANG` settings for `LC_COLLATE` and others.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, `LC_ALL` is an env var you **DO NOT** want to set from what I have been reading.  It is there for developers for debugging purposes when they need to quickly change all the locale settings ie. env vars you listed above for a particular environment as it overwrites / supersedes all the other locale env vars, thus that is why it is left unset.

cheers 
Chris

Answer (score -1):

ZSH seems not to source ~/.profile

I added the two export statements into ~/.zshrc and the issue is solved.

Comment: The right file to set these is: `~/.zprofile`. You don't need to repeat these settings for every shell or subshell: once per session is enough. Moreover, once `LANG` is set, and if the `LC_…` aren't different, they don't need to be set, they will inherit `${LANG}`.